# ASP.NET Core / EF Core LINQ statement

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have 3 related entities:

- `PurchaseOrder` (Id, ProjectId, Source, CompanyId, ...)
- `Company` (Id, Name, ...)
- `Contacts` (Id, CompanyId, Email, AutoEM, ...)

Each purchase order has a related company and each company can have one or more contacts where one of them is set as the primary or default contact (eg: `AutoEM == true`).

I would like the LINQ to return a set of `PurchaseOrder` rows for a selected `ProjectId` and include, on each row, the company name its for, and the contact email for the primary contact for that company.

I was able to get the PO and Company info displayed on my page, but have not been able to figure out how to include the primary contact which has `AutoEM == true`. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
pos = context.PurchaseOrder
             .Where(p => p.ProjectId == Int32.Parse(id))
             .Include(p => p.company)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `.Include(c => c.Contacts).Where(c=> c.IsDefault=="Y")`

Comment: This is as close as i can get to code that is not raising any errors. I changed IsDefault to "AutoEm" ==true.  Include(cc => cc.company.contacts).Where(cc => cc.company.contacts.AutoEm==true). Its not finding the AutoEm column name.

Comment: Please post the error code. In your example table the column seems to be called `IsDefault`

Comment: Thanks for your help Nick. I edited my question to correct the column names. I'm using VS 2019 and as I'm typing out cc.company.contacts its showing me via auto suggest all the column names etc for each entity except the contacts entity. Its not showing any of the column names just things like Where(), FirstOrDefault() etc. I'm probably doing something dumb.

Comment: I'm guessing there is no relationship set up in your model. I'm guessing this might be because it doesn't allow many to many relationships.

Comment: It's a long time since I've done EF, but autosuggest just reflects what's in your autogenerated classes. A simple check would be to see if you can select from `Contacts` on it's own. Does `x=context.Contacts.Where(c => c.AutoEm == true)` work?

Comment: Also just a comment, needing to use `Int32.Parse(id)` is a red flag - it appears your database datatypes are not consistent

Comment: ... and one last comment..... think about whether you really want that `ToList()` on the end,

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to include the primary contact which has AutoEM == true.

The condition (where statement) should be applied to the include of Contacts. The use of "ThenInclude" is to guarantee that related Company is added first and then including related Contacts where AutoEM == true.

I suggest the following update to the code:

```
pos = context.PurchaseOrder  
        .Where(p => p.ProjectId == Int32.Parse(id))  
        .Include(p => p.company)  
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Contacts.Where(c => c.AutoEM == true))  
        .ToList();
```

Comment: No syntax errors on this code but when i run it i get "Lambda expression used inside include is not valid".

Comment: It's interesting that EF has the concept of joining tables in a certain order, whereas SQL (rightly) does not.

Comment: I made a small yet important edit the code in answer. The Where clause in "p.Contacts.Where(" should start with capital W to use the one in Linq. Please try it and let me know @MichaelW